# Trying to understand why this Python code works

Tags: python, oop

This is an implementation of the [Ford-Fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) given on Wikipedia. I understand the algorithm just fine, my issue is this : the `add_edge` and `max_flow` methods access the `redge` (reverse edge) of an `edge` as `edge.redge`, but the `Edge` class has no attribute called `redge`. In spite of this, the code runs fine.

```
class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, u, v, w):
        self.source = u
        self.sink = v  
        self.capacity = w
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s->%s:%s" % (self.source, self.sink, self.capacity)

class FlowNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.adj = {}
        self.flow = {}

    def add_vertex(self, vertex):
        self.adj[vertex] = []

    def get_edges(self, v):
        return self.adj[v]

    def add_edge(self, u, v, w=0):
        if u == v:
            raise ValueError("u == v")
        edge = Edge(u,v,w)
        redge = Edge(v,u,0)
        edge.redge = redge
        redge.redge = edge
        self.adj[u].append(edge)
        self.adj[v].append(redge)
        self.flow[edge] = 0
        self.flow[redge] = 0

    def find_path(self, source, sink, path):
        if source == sink:
            return path
        for edge in self.get_edges(source):
            residual = edge.capacity - self.flow[edge]
            if residual > 0 and edge not in path:
                result = self.find_path( edge.sink, sink, path + [edge]) 
                if result != None:
                    return result

    def max_flow(self, source, sink):
        path = self.find_path(source, sink, [])
        while path != None:
            residuals = [edge.capacity - self.flow[edge] for edge in path]
            flow = min(residuals)
            for edge in path:
                self.flow[edge] += flow
                self.flow[edge.redge] -= flow
            path = self.find_path(source, sink, [])
        return sum(self.flow[edge] for edge in self.get_edges(source))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python classes don't declare object attributes, they are stored in per-instance dictionaries. The `Edge` object only happens to start with three attributes, `source`, `sink`, and `capacity`. Later it gains a new attribute, `redge`. This is standard in many scripting languages, Python included.

Having said that, do note that the practice of adding attributes later is considered obfuscated by some. For the sake of clarity it is a good idea to initialize all attributes that the class intends to use in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The code **sets** the `redge` attributes:

```
edge = Edge(u,v,w)
redge = Edge(v,u,0)
edge.redge = redge
redge.redge = edge
```

From there on out both the `edge` and `redge` objects *do* have an `redge` attributes.

In other words, in Python you are free to add attributes to instances anywhere in the code, you are not limited to the class definition or the methods on the class itself. `self` is just another reference to an instance, the same way that `edge` and `redge` are references.

Answer (score 2):

You are free to assign new attributes to an existing user-defined object with:

```
obj.prop = value
```

Once assigned, they exist.

You can see that the `__init__` method does the same thing: it just assigns attributes, and then they exist.